# Почему не получается удалить элементы QGridLayout?(Python3, PyQt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qgridlayout

Недавно я уже задавал подобный вопрос, но теперь код немного другой, и я никак не могу найти причину проблемы.

Ниже оставлю этот код. В нем есть три класса - `ListWidget`, `Label` и `MyWindow`. `ListWidget` создает резиновую ленту, а `Label` создает виджет QLabel с закругленным изображением. 
На эти классы не стоит обращать внимания, они точно правильно выполняют свои функции. Проблема(проблемы) в классе `MyWindow`.

1. Тут я создаю кнопку `simple_btn`, которая потом попадает в
   вертикальный контейнер `box2`. Пока она не выполняет и не должна
   выполнять никаких функций.
2. Создаю `listWidget` - копию класса `ListWidget`, который наполняю виджетами QLable(`label1`, `label2`, `label3`), полученными из класса `Label`.
3. Создаю `scrollArea`(QScrollArea), но пока нигде не размещаю.
4. Создаю QGridLayout - `box1`, куда первым виджетом(0, 0) добавляю
   `listWidget`.
5. К виджетам `label1` , `label2` и `label3` привязываю метод класса `MyWindow` - `click()`(при этом передаю этому методу аргумент `num`),
   который с помощью `hide()` скрывает `listWidget` и создает
   привязанный к `scrollArea` контейнер QGridLayout - `box3`, если он
   еще не был создан. `box3` наполняется кнопками, число которых зависит от аргумента `num`. В вертикальный
   контейнер `box2` попадает кнопка `back_btn`.
6. К кнопке `back_btn` привязваю метод `onButton`. Этот метод должен
   удалять все виджеты контейнера `box3`, скрывать `scrollArea` с
   помощью `hide()` и делать обратно видимым `listWidget` с помощью
   `show()`.

**В чем пробема:**

Если число кнопок в контейнере `box3` будет равным, при нажатии на любой QLabel, никаких ошибок не возникает. Но, т.к. теперь я регулирую число кнопок для каждого QLabel, что-то начало идти не так в методе `onButton()`, который удаляет элементы из `box3`. Если нажать сначала на `label3`, которому соответствует три кнопки в `box3`, а потом на `label1`, которому соответствует одна кнопка, в консоль попадет **сообщение об ошибке:**

> w = self.box3.itemAtPosition(row, col).widget()
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'widget'

Я заметил, что, если следующий QLabel, который будет нажат, создаст в `box3` **больше** кнопок, чем создавал предыдущий QLabel, ошибок **не возникает**. Если следующий QLabel, который будет нажат, создаст в `box3` **меньше** кнопок, чем создавал предыдущий QLabel, **возникнет ошибка**.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как мне починить код?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.setWindowTitle('ListWidget')
        #self.setStyleSheet('border-style: hidden;')
        self.resize(520, 400)

        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.setEditTriggers(self.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAction)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ContiguousSelection)

        self.setFlow(self.LeftToRight)
        self.setWrapping(True)
        self.setResizeMode(self.Adjust)

        self.setSpacing(10)

        self._rubberPos  = None
        self._rubberBand = None #QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)

    def makeItem(self, lb):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self)
        item.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(140, 140))
        self.setItemWidget(item, lb)


class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setMaximumSize(140, 140)
        self.setMinimumSize(140, 140)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)    

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(140, 140, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.simple_btn  = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        self.simple_btn.setFixedSize(100, 60)

        self.listWidget = ListWidget()

        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.content_widget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.label1 = Label('picture1.png')
        self.listWidget.makeItem(self.label1)
        self.label1.clicked.connect(lambda num=2: self.click(num))
        self.label2 = Label('picture1.png')
        self.listWidget.makeItem(self.label2)
        self.label2.clicked.connect(lambda num=3: self.click(num))
        self.label3 = Label('picture1.png')
        self.listWidget.makeItem(self.label3)
        self.label3.clicked.connect(lambda num=4: self.click(num))

        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.box2.addWidget(self.simple_btn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)                                     
        self.box1.addWidget(self.listWidget, 0, 0)
        self.box1.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.box1.addLayout(self.box2, 0, 1) 

    def click(self, num):
        self.listWidget.hide()

        if not hasattr(self, 'box3'):
            self.box1.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0)
            self.box3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.content_widget)
        else:
            self.scrollArea.show()

        for n in range(1, num):
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'Button{n}')
            self.box3.addWidget(btn, n-1, 0)

        self.back_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Back', clicked=self.onButton) 
        self.back_btn.setFixedSize(100, 60)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.back_btn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

    def onButton(self):
        self.back_btn.deleteLater()
        col = 0
        for row in range(self.box3.rowCount()):
            w = self.box3.itemAtPosition(row, col).widget()
            w.deleteLater()
        self.scrollArea.hide()
        self.listWidget.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я не проверял вашу логику, но починить код можно так:

```
...
def onButton(self):
    self.back_btn.deleteLater()
    col = 0
    for row in range(self.box3.rowCount()):
        if self.box3.itemAtPosition(row, col) is not None:                   # +++
            w = self.box3.itemAtPosition(row, col).widget()
            w.deleteLater()

    self.scrollArea.hide()
    self.listWidget.show()
...
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное:)

Comment: `w.deleteLater()` надо сдвинуть вправо

Comment: @Alexander Chernin, спасибо:)